# Having a AutoComplete combobox that does NOT allow custom text

Tags: c#, winforms

C# WinForms:
I used a Combobox with these properties:
DropDownStyle: DropDown
AutoCompleteSource: ListItems
AutoCompleteMode: SuggestAppend

so now when I type in combobox, it suggests items from the list of its items.Good. But the issue is that I don't want to be able to type whatever I want, I just want to be able to type from the valid items that are in its list. How can I fix this part?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You'd have to populate the **Items** list with your values (either manually or via databinding), and then set **DropDownStyle** to `DropDownList`.

The Combobox won't look like a Textbox, but when it has focus, typing into it will auto-select the best match from the Items list.

(That's the recommended way to set a Combobox to not allow custom text.)

Alternately, if you'd like the style to be DropDown, capture the `KeyPress` event of the control, and do a quick check of the control's text plus `e.KeyChar`, and if it's not found in the list, set `e.Handled = True`.  This will block all keypresses that would result in a word that's not in the list.

Comment: thanks but that doesn't work. Yes it will prevent it from typing whatever we like but it also breaks AutoCompletion. Still we can type but ALWAYS it will show the whole list and won't filter them.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly like auto complete, but if you set DropDownStyle to DropDownList, it will only allow entries that are in the Items collection.  However, the default behavior of this mode is that every letter you type jumps to the first match starting with that letter.  So, if you want to allow them to continue typing additional characters past the first letter, you can set AutoCompleteSource to ListItems and then set AutoCompleteMode to Append .

Answer (score 1):

This matches with the strings in the combo box this works.

```
int index = combobox1.FindString(combobox1.Text);
  if (index < 0)
  {
  MessageBox.Show("Invalid Record");
  combobox1.Focus();
  return;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The combo box control doesn't support this directly.

You'll need to write handlers to verify that an item from the list has been entered, and prompt the user if not.

Answer (score 0):

Other option might be registering to the `TextChanged`or `TextUpdated` event and in case the already typed text doesn't fit you conditions, change it appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to set default value while leave or clear selection.

```
private void comboBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == -1)
       {
            if (comboBox1.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                comboBox1.Text = "";
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

DropDownStyle has 3 Options
Simple
DropDown
DropDownList
Select DropDownList
AllowDrop is set to True
Locked is set to False

Comment: this does not answer the question -1